# Comment traduire "Informatique de gestion" en anglais ?

Tags: informatique

J'avais pensé à

> *"Computer Science Management"*

mais ça me semble bizarre. Habituellement ce que je fais c'est aller sur Wikipédia en français et trouver l'article correspondant en anglais mais dans ce cas la page *"Informatique de Gestion"* n'est pas reliée à une page anglaise. Des idées ?

Comment: Je le traduirais par *business computing* mais la question est hors-sujet ici puisqu'elle ne concerne pas le français

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a apparemment beaucoup de traductions possibles :

- administrative data processing
- business data processing
- business computing
- commercial data processing
- commercial computing
- business-oriented computing

A vous de voir si vous voulez mettre plus en avant le côté commercial ou le côté administratif de la chose

Source : http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364055